# React - the downloaded pdf is blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, axios, download

At first, I send a GET request for the pdf data

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  baseURL: 'https://my-site.com',
};
const axiosInstance = axios.create({config});
 
const pdf = await axiosInstance.get('url', {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken, Accept: '*/*' },
})
```

The value of `pdf` is the same as below
[image]

Then I tried to download the file

```
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([pdf]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', `FileName.pdf`);

    // Append to html link element page
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    // Start download
    link.click();
```

I can download the pdf file successfully, but the pdf is blank when I open it.

How to fix it?

Comment: This may sound obvious...but do you need to put the `pdf` variable in brackets instead of `new Blob(pdf)` ?

Comment: @DennisQuan `Argument of type 'pdf' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPart[]'.
  Type 'PdfResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'BlobPart[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.`

Comment: @DennisQuan If I remove the brackets, the error above will show

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by adding `responseType: 'blob'`

```
const pdf = await axiosInstance.get('url', {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken, Accept: '*/*' },
        responseType: 'blob',
})
```